# error on line 5 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

Why am I getting the following error:

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 5 at column 1:
>   Extra content at the end of the document Below is a rendering of the
>   page up to the first error.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

    @header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

$dir   = substr(trim($_REQUEST['Body']),0,3);
$msg   = substr(trim($_REQUEST['Body']),3);
$phone =  '0'.substr(trim($_REQUEST['From']),4);

 if($dir == 'PRV'){
        process_PreVoting($phone,$date,$msg);
    }

function process_PreVoting($phone,$date,$msg){
        //$mysqliobject = new dbobject();
        global $mysqli;
        $details = explode(";",$msg);
        $officer_id = $details[1];
        $userpassword = $details[2];
        $lga =  $details[3];
        $ward = $details[4];
        $poll_unit = $details[5];
        $total_queue = $details[6];
        if($total_queue=='')$total_queue=0;
        $comments = $details[7];
        $device_entry_date = $details[8];
        //$resp = $mysqliobject->getcheckdetails($officer_id,$userpassword);
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM master where phoneNo = '$phone' OR phonetwo = '$phone'";
              $st   =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
              $resp  =  mysqli_num_rows($st);
             //$PtaW =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($st);
        if($resp > 0)
        {
            // check if record already exists
            $sqls = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT officer_code FROM pre_voting_info WHERE officer_code='$officer_id'");
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($sqls);
            if($count > 0)
            {
            mysqli_query($mysqli,"update pre_voting_info set total_queue='$total_queue', comments='$comments', modify_entry_date='$device_entry_date' WHERE officer_code='$officer_id'");
            }
            else
            {

$resps = mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into pre_voting_info(pu_name,ward_name,lga_name,total_queue,comments,entry_date,device_entry_date,officer_code) values ('$poll_unit','$ward','$lga','$total_queue','$comments','$device_entry_date','$device_entry_date','$officer_id')");

                if($resps) {
                    return "PreVoting Post Successfully Added";
                }
                else {
            return "Error, could not add PreVoting Details. ".$mysqli->error;
                }

            $my_file = "echolog.txt";
            $handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
            fwrite($handle, "PRE-VOTING SQL: ".$sql);
            fclose($handle);

            }


        }else{

            return "Invalid User Credentails: ".$mysqli->error;
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i');
            mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into logtable (phoneNo,title,logMsg,pu,logDate) values ('$phone','Accreditation','$info','$poll_unit','$date')");

        }

    }//Function close
```

When I preview my source code on the browser, the only thing it outputted is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: BTW your "logging" doesn't make any sense as the code will never reach this line because of the `return` statement before---> `return "Invalid User Credentails:...`

Comment: @B001ᛦ, I have seen that before actually posting mine and it didn't in any way help my situation. My request is coming from an droid sms application route through twilio and processed using the php codes I posted.

Comment: @B001ᛦ, Do you suggest I should remove the the logging

Comment: _Do you suggest I should remove the the logging_ There is no logging.. your code will never arrive at this line...... _My request is coming from an droid sms..._ ok? but you are still generating xml.. so seems to be the same problem...look at @Zenas answer

Answer (score 0):

There must be some content to be a valid xml document, for example this is enough:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root></root>
```

Comment: Could you please explain further. I don't really understand what you are saying. Should I put my code in between   <root></root>. Please I really need help..

Comment: You should put any code you need to put in there, it just won't work when there's only this line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and nothing else. Also make sure your script outputs valid xml to the file and not plain text or something like that.